# progressbar during query processing in mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I want to show **progress bar** when am **submitting data** and **Fetching data** from **MySQL** database using python

But i want my progress bar to run on **tkinter** window
Any one with idea on that who can help...to do that please

Comment: It is very hard for us to help you without a minimal reproducible example. See this article from the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has a built in progress bar you can call like this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(False, False)


progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode="indeterminate", length=150)
progress_bar.pack()

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start progress bar", command=progress_bar.start)
start_button.pack()

stop_button = tk.Button(root, text="Stop progess bar", command=progress_bar.stop)
stop_button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Op wanted to submit data and Fetching data from MySQL database..